# How to print the flat map values from the list using scala

Tags: scala

```
  val list2 = (List(List(2, 3, 4, 5, 5), 2, List(2, 3)))
   def flatenlist(ls: List[Any]): List[Any] = ls flatMap {
    case hi: List[_] => flatenlist(hi)
    case e => List(e)
    }
   println(flatenlist(ls ,List[Any])) // ERROR LINE 
   }
```

For the above code to print the flat map values using recursion how can i modify the println values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the last statement with this one will work perfectly alright.

```
println(flatenlist(list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Method flattenList only takes 1 argument, not 2.